# Choose the right algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, algorithm

I need to select the most suitable ML algorithm for an academic project. I have a dataset earn from lab which includes the long of an element and 3 factors that we believe impact the long of the mentioned element. I want to predict the length of the element by using those 3 factors.
Probably I should use supervised algos but which one?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to refer to scikit-learn's [Choosing the right estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) cheatsheet, using it of course with a bit of consideration and thought.

In your case we are talking about a **supervised regression** problem in which you have to predict a numeric value from three other values. The first thing to note is that, having only three input features, you should probably first **plot** the data and try exploring it with your own eyes. You may find out that one or more of those features have a clear relationship with the target variable, for example a linear correlation.
In that case, you could try fitting a [linear model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) to your data.

One important aspect that you don't mention is the **number of data points** you have available. Having enough data for both training and testing is essential, although the exact number depends on how complex the relationship between variables is. Good luck.